# Laptop memory always almost full when idle

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, memory, performance

I got a Acer E 14 laptop with 4gb of ram and an i3 5005U processor. I was wondering why it is lagging so much. Even if I only open sublime (I switched to sublime since vs code cause so much more lag) and a google chrome browser with one tab (my web project). Then I noticed i got something like this. This problem does not occur past months. Maybe my laptop was too old thats why it lags?

[image: Idle only]

On idle only. No other programs except for task manager.

I also tried methods that I searched from the internet like going to `regedit` and switching the value of `start` to `4` from `ndu` folder. Also tried disk defragment and cleanup, add virtual memory stuff and it kinda boost a little bit but after a few days of using, the problem occurs again. I also formatted it but it still occurs and i think it is worsen.

Can someone tell me what should I do about this. I know i can add a new RAM but the stores are closed for now because of quarantine. What are the other remedies for this kind of problem?

PS: Is this the right stack exchange website for this kind of question?

Comment: First things first: you've got 4GB of RAM, which, nowadays, is barely enough for Windows itself, but that's OK, I've got a budget laptop with only 2GB of RAM running Windows 10 1909 32-bit, and it works reasonably fast, all things considered. However, it never maxes out its RAM the way yours does, which leads me to ask the next question: is all your RAM accounted for? If you go to Performance monitor, do you see your 4GB of RAM in there? How many RAM sticks do you have on this PC? Is it 1 x 4GB or 2 x 2GB, for example? How about pagefile(s)? Are they enabled, and if so what's their total size?

Comment: It would also be interesting to know how many processes and services are running on your PC when it's idling like in the pic. There's a way to bring down the total number of svchost services, for example, that could help. Or not. We need more info.

Comment: Yes i got 4gb of ram in my resource monitor @Didier. I dont know what processes is running at my computer i even dont have running task and in my taskbar tray i got only intel graphics running. I disabled windows defender and such stuff. And still i got something like that. I cannot use my laptop properly. The ram of this laptop is a single 4gb. I dont know much about you say like sysfile and stuff. This is all i can say

Comment: When you open Task Manager, like in your pic, and go to the Performance tab, you'll see how many processes and services are running at any given moment. Restart your PC after disabling Fast Startup (in Control Panel, under System & Security, Power options, click on "Choose the action when closing the lid", and disable Fast Startup after clicking on "Change currently unavailable parameters/settings"). Upon restart, when you PC has been idling for a couple minutes, open Task Manager, go to Performance and check how many processes are running in the Processor section.

Comment: Okay will do that. I just wondering why my ram is full. Maybe i got memory leak? Is that what they say?

Comment: After i did what you told me i got something like this https://imgur.com/a/RINppI1 @Didier. What does fast startup do anyways?

Comment: also my performance tab and resource monitor https://imgur.com/a/tHJTtE4 @Didier. What other methods should I do in order to boost my laptops performance? Thanks for this btw

Comment: I really don't know why you're worried about your RAM, because in the last screen you posted, it shows only 41% of it is in use. That's pretty good, considering you're running Windows 10. It's not going to get much better, unless you install more RAM after the lockdown (you can also order it online). Am I missing something here?

Comment: no. Its okay right now i think. I just need some advice what are other options to boost my laptop performance. @Didier

Comment: Aside from adding RAM, there's not much to do. Your CPU isn't very fast to begin with, but you can't change that. You can try to install a RAM disk and direct some temp folders to it (your browser's, for example, and your user account's), to save on I/O on your hard drive or SSD, but that's about it. I'd recommend ImDisk as a RAM disk program. It's easy to configure, and it does the job. Plus, you can't beat the price... Look it up and try it.